# Adding rows and columns to a table dynamically with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
function addRowToTable()
{
  var tbl = document.getElementById('tblSample');
  var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
  // if there's no header row in the table, then iteration = lastRow + 1
  var iteration = lastRow;
  var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);

  // left cell
  var cellLeft = row.insertCell(0);
  var textNode = document.createTextNode(iteration);
  cellLeft.appendChild(textNode);

  // right cell
  var cellRight = row.insertCell(1);
  var el = document.createElement('input');
  el.type = 'text';
  el.name = 'txtRow' + iteration;
  el.id = 'txtRow' + iteration;
  el.size = 40;

  el.onkeypress = keyPressTest;
  cellRight.appendChild(el);

  // select cell
  var cellRightSel = row.insertCell(2);
  var sel = document.createElement('select');
  sel.name = 'selRow' + iteration;
  sel.options[0] = new Option('text zero', 'value0');
  sel.options[1] = new Option('text one', 'value1');
  cellRightSel.appendChild(sel);
}
```

How to translate this from DOM calls to jQuery?Can anyone give sample code .

Answer (score 9):

I would avoid using strings of HTML and keep creating DOM elements like you had before.  jQuery makes this really easy:

```
var row = $("<tr>");
row.append( $("<td>").text("hello") );
$("#tblSample").append(row);
```

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2 for more info.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this (but without `select`): http://jsfiddle.net/dVBMc/3/

UPDATE:
http://jsfiddle.net/dVBMc/6/

```
function addRowToTable(table, cell1, cell2) {
    var row;
    row = "<tr><td>" + cell1 + "</td><td>" + cell2 + "</td></tr>";
    table.append(row);
}
```

Usage:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        addRowToTable($('table'), 'cell1 content', 'cell2 content');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to simply use `$('#tblSample').append('<tr> ... </tr>')`, manually entering the html string (if it's constant). You can also read the html from somewhere else, for more readable code:

```
 $('#tblSample').append($('div#blank-row-container').html());
```