# Clone table row and math function in jquery - how to correctly tackle?

Tags: jquery, html, clone

I don't know where to begin?

(textfield A / textfield B) = textfield C

And repeat/clone this table row automaticly .change on keyup of textfield B.  Basically meaning that after the first calculation is made, another row will popup with unique ids etc.

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <td><input type="text" id="A" name="A"></td>
   <td><input type="text" id="B" name="B"></td>
   <td><input type="text" id="C" name="C" value=""></td>
  </tr>
</table>


// Clone table rows
$(function() {
    var i = 1;
    $("#A").clone(function() {
               $("table tr:first").clone(true).find("input").each(function() {
            $(this).val('').attr('id', function(_, id) { return id + i });
            $(this).val('').attr('name', function(_, name) { return name + i });
            }).end().appendTo("table");

        i++;

        $("#C").val(Math.round(($("#A").val() / $("#B").val()) * 100 )+ "%");

    });
```

});

Comment: check out this question, I think it will get you going: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574900/how-to-append-a-textbox-to-a-table-row-with-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried hard to understand your question. I have interpreted your question as:

- On keyup of A or B, calculate A/B, and put the result in C
- On change of B, add a new row with unique IDs.
- Continue.

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/vpsv9/**

HTML:

```
<table id="math-table">
  <tr>
   <td><input type="text" id="A1" name="A"></td>
   <td><input type="text" id="B1" name="B"></td>
   <td><input type="text" id="C1" name="C" value=""></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
// The first requirement
$("#math-table input").live("keyup", function(){
    var id = this.id.match(/\d+/);
    $("#C"+id).val(  $("#A"+id).val() / $("#B"+id).val()  );
});

// The second requirement:
var uniqueIds = $("#math-table tr").length;
$("#math-table input[id^='B']").live("change", function(){
    var $thisRow = $(this).closest("tr"),
        $clone = $thisRow.clone(),             // Clone row
        $inputs = $clone.find("input").val("");// Reset values, return all inputs
    uniqueIds++; //Increment ID
    $inputs[0].id = "A" + uniqueIds;
    $inputs[1].id = "B" + uniqueIds;
    $inputs[2].id = "C" + uniqueIds;
  //$inputs.eq(0).focus();           // Optionally, focus on the next input field
    $thisRow.after($clone);                    // Add row after current one
});
```

Comment: Thank you!  You were spot on with my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Fwiw, I have this solution which is very close to Rob's answer : http://jsfiddle.net/49DGP/2/

Comment: In either of the two, how do you keep from displaying "infinity"

Comment: Where you calculate the value of the third input, you can check if the dividend is 0 (therefore infinity) and maybe provide a warning for the user or put a different text for the val(). Sometimes, you'll get NaN, same applies in this condition too. I think seeing something either NaN or Infinity is better than not seeing anything because people might think something is not working in the form. Of course, for user experience, you can maybe highlight the border of the problem input element. For example, if you are entering string in the first input, that element can glow red...